# How do I declare an object as field in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I keep getting the Java error `The constructor LocalDate (int, int, int) is not visible`. I am trying to create a private field and initialize it.

How do I do this properly:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
    
public class Registration {
    private registrationDate = new LocalDate.of (0,0,0);
}
...
```

Comment: It is without `new`, a static method `of` yielding a new object: `= LocalDate.of (0,0,0);`

Comment: Get rid of the `new` and provide a type for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the biggest issue is that you shouldn't be using the `new` keyword because you aren't invoking `LocalDate`'s constructor. `LocalDate.of()` is just a method that you would call like any other.

You also should declare what type `registrationDate` is. So try:

```
private LocalDate registrationDate = LocalDate.of(0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private LocalDate registrationDate = LocalDate.of(0,0,0);
```

Two errors were there, first is that you have not declared the type of variable `registrationDate` and the second is that `new` is not required here as you are using a static method of `LocalDate` class.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDate.of` is what you call in Java a static method. Static methods do not require you to create a new version of the class. Instead, everything they need to operate is passed into the method via it's parameters. To fix this, remove the `new` keyword.

You are also not setting the type of the registrationDate object. Unlike other languages like Kotlin that can infer type, in Java you need to state exactly what the type is. To do this, you'll need to put a LocalDate in between `private` and `registrationDate`.

Putting that all together, it should look like this:

```
private LocalDate registrationDate = LocalDate.of(0,0,0);
```